# Django Template error: “category_list takes 2 arguments”

Tags: python, django

Django template not loading from DB

I'm in the process of changing the templates to a new design. During this process, the category list stopped loading.

> “category_list takes 2 arguments”

In the html file, “category_list” is being loaded with:

```
{% category_list request.path %}
```

Can someone explain what it means by “takes 2 arguments” in this situation?

Edit: 
Here is the custom template tag:

```
def category_list(request_path):
    list_cache_key = 'active_category_link_list'
    active_categories = cache.get(list_cache_key)
    if not active_categories:
        active_categories = Category.active.all()
        cache.set(list_cache_key, active_categories, CACHE_TIMEOUT)
    return {
        'active_categories': active_categories,
        'request_path': request_path
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`category_list` must be a [Django custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags) that takes two arguments.

In your current template syntax your first argument is `request.path`. Look in your code for the definition of function `category_list` and check what arguments it should receive and add the second argument.

Comment: I've added the template tag definition. It looks like it's returning 2 arguments.

Comment: @pythondjango It's returning 1 argument; a dict with two keys `active_categories` and `request_path`. Can you post the full exception traceback?

Comment: it returns two, but it gets 1 `request_path` - just add `*args, **kwargs` and check with a `print` command what you get from `request.path`

Comment: Added *args, **kwargs but same issue. Everything was working yesterday and no .py code was changed, only the templates. Doesn't that mean it's a template issue?

Comment: where did you add *args and **kwargs ?

Comment: the category_list definition posted above. 
def category_list(request_path, *args, **kwargs):

Comment: ok - now have a look at this ( http://stackoverflow.com/a/3394898/1073606 ). Just `print` your args and kwargs to see in developementserver `python manage.py runserver` what `request.path` is sending to your function

Comment: @init3 I'm interacting with a web server with apache. I'm not sure how to print what you're asking.

Comment: just connect via ssh to your webserver. Change to the directory of your project and run `python manage.py runserver <IPOFYOURSERVER>:8000` then browse to the ip like `http://1.1.1.1:8000`. You'll get the same error, but you will see the output of `print` in your ssh-console

Comment: The issue was there was extra markup that I found was screwing with everything in the definition. I deleted that and poof. No more errors. Thanks guys, you got me on the right track.